# Git directory structure changed after branching

Tags: git, branch

I have a git project with two branches. After making branch for featureX the directory structure in main branch has changed. Is there a simple way to update the directory structure of featureX -branch based on the master branch?

Comment: Doesn't `git rebase` do that? `git checkout featureX && git rebase master` should bring the feature branch up to date with master...

Comment: Please add the commands that were executed.